# Is shortened if conditions possible

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

We know that you can shorten an if statement by typing

```js
(condition) ? true : false;
```

But is it also possible to check 2 variables if they're both an i.e. string:

```js
var string1 = "text"
var string2 = "text"

if(string1 && string2 == "text") {
    // Anything else
}
```

I personally don't think because it will check if `string1` exists and that `string2` is `"text"`. But maybe I'm wrong

Comment: You mean `if( string1 === "text" && string2 === "text" )` ?

Answer (score 0):

It will check if `string1` exists and then it will check if `string2` is `text`. I don't think so you could check 2 variables.